# Getting integer while using strtok() in string

Tags: c, string

I'm new to C and need your help.
I'm trying to get an integer from a string that has a number in it.
I have with me a code I did but the only problem is when I'm assigning years as int i think I'm getting some sort of an address. Is there a way to get my char years into an in years?

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <string.h>

 int main()
 {
   char sentence[]="trade_#_2009_#_invest_#_DEALING";

   char *word=strtok(sentence, "_#_");
   char *year=strtok(NULL,"_#_");   // assigning NULL for previousely where it left off
   char *definition=strtok(NULL,"_#_");
   char *synonyms=strtok(NULL,"_#_");

   printf("%s\n", word);
   printf("%s\n", year);
   printf("%s\n", definition);
   printf("%s\n", synonyms);

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int iYear = 0;
sscanf(year,"%d",&iYear);
```

This should be the simplest.

You might also want to look at `atoi` function.

Comment: I would suggest `strtoXX` rather than `atoi` - the former have error catching capability unlike the latter (and unlike `sscanf` for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

Use [strtol](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/) or [strtoul](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/).

Here's an example taken from the `strtol` page that I linked to above:

```
/* strtol example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* strtol */

int main ()
{
  char szNumbers[] = "2001 60c0c0 -1101110100110100100000 0x6fffff";
  char * pEnd;
  long int li1, li2, li3, li4;
  li1 = strtol (szNumbers,&pEnd,10);
  li2 = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd,16);
  li3 = strtol (pEnd,&pEnd,2);
  li4 = strtol (pEnd,NULL,0);
  printf ("The decimal equivalents are: %ld, %ld, %ld and %ld.\n", li1, li2, li3, li4);
  return 0;
}
```